# Some apps not available on play store after lcd_density change in build.prop

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-store, cyanogenmod

I changed the ro.sf.lcd_density in the build.prop on my Galaxy SII from the default 240 to 190. It made everything smaller, creating more space and increasing the quality of use for me personaly.

Everything seemed okay at first, applications were behaving normal, but I have a problem with installing some apps from the Play Store. I can search for an app, go into its details, only to find a message on the top saying that my device isn't compatible.

I have found a workaround but it takes too much time since I have to reboot my device twice for it. My current workaround is this:

1. Change my ro.sf.lcd_density back to 240
2. Reboot
3. Search for and install the app
4. Change the ro.sf.lcd_density back to 190
5. Reboot

After that the app still works, so no issues there. But the process just takes too much time. Is there another thing I can do to install these apps without my mentioned workaround?

Comment: Keep in mind some apps don't work in changed DPI Settings(apart from normal). You might be interested in ParanaoidAndroid which let's you change DPI on per-app basis.

Comment: Hey @wayback thanks for the tip. Installing it as my dualboot ROM right now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a modified version of the Play Store that removes device restrictions.

See [this xda thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1839871) for more info and the download link to your version of android.

It also disables self-updating of the Play Store so your modified version wont be replaced by a newer official one.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks! Installed and confirmed that I can now install apps that were previously restricted.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used it but a quick search on the play store suggests this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.birdapi.android.dpipro

It specifies that :

> This is the only LCD Density app that can fix the "This device is not supported" error message in the Android market when using an unsupported dpi!

Note: I'm not affiliated with this product

Comment: Yea, found that one too. But since I can change LCD Density without using an app, I want to fix this without an app too. That app is able to fix this issue, so there must be a way to fix this by setting the right paramaters somewhere myself.

Comment: This one allows you to try to set the density without rebooting https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.lcddensity - it may not work, but worth a try?